# C# ASP.NET SQL Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

How would I use a SQL Data Source to return the value from the select statement into a variable?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsProfile" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MYDB %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserProfileInformation] WHERE ([UserID] = @UserID)" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="Verified" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

I have a colum that is called Verified in the database that is a bit. It is either a 0 or a 1.  This tells me if the user profile has been verified by the admin. Is there a way to take the return value from the select statement and put it into the Verified parameter? This way I can access that parameter value in the code behind and manipulate the page based on a 0 or a 1? Thanks!

Comment: Are you attempting to do this in pure ASP?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you cannot do it without code-behind. At least not the way you can respect yourself the next day.